# What represents the letters inside brackets?

Tags: javascript, monetjs

I'm using a library called Monet.js, in the documentation has descriptions like this: `Maybe[A].map(fn: A => B) : Maybe[B]`

I dont know what represents the letters inside the brackets.

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: I suppose it could be a classname but I don't know monetjs.

Comment: Can you provide more context and a link to the documentation?

Answer (score 3):

> Generic Types JavaScript doesn't have generic types but it's useful to
> know about them when dealing with Monads. For instance the List monad
> is a type that requires another type, such as a string or integer or
> some other type before it can be constructed. So you would have a List
> of Strings or a List of Integers or generically a List of As where A
> is a type you will supply. Now of course this is JavaScript and you
> can do as you please even though it doesn't make sense. But to make
> things clearer (hopefully) we will attempt to do show generics or type
> parameters thusly:
>
> ```
> List[A]
> ```
>
> Which means a List of As. Though of course you will have to keep track
> of the types yourself.

The documentation is in the [monet.js readme](https://github.com/monet/monet.js/blob/master/docs/README.md).